# Are there any differences between Approximate Dynamic programming and Adaptive dynamic programming

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I have been reading some literature on Reinforcement learning and I **FEEL** that both terms are used interchangeably. Are there **ANY** differences between the two terms or are they used to refer to the same thing, namely (from [here](http://adp.princeton.edu/Papers/Powell-NRLWhat%20you%20should%20know%20about%20approximate%20dynamic%20programming.pdf), which defines **Approximate** DP):

> The essence of approximate dynamic program-ming is to replace the true value function $V_t(S_t)$ with some sort of statistical approximation that we refer to as $\bar{V}_t(S_t)$ ,an idea that was suggested in Ref?.
>
> The second step in approximate dynamic programming is that instead of working backward through time (computing the value of being in each state), ADP steps forward in time, although there are different variations which combine stepping forward in time with backward sweeps to update the value of being in a state

Reference:
Powell, Warren B. "What you should know about approximate dynamic programming." Naval Research Logistics (NRL) 56.3 (2009): 239-249.

Answer (score 1):

They both refer to the same thing.

[Reference](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4840325):

F. -Y. Wang, H. Zhang and D. Liu, "Adaptive Dynamic Programming: An Introduction," in IEEE Computational Intelligence Magazine, vol. 4, no. 2, pp. 39-47, May 2009, doi: 10.1109/MCI.2009.932261.